# How to make compiler skip a function based on the version?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to expose a function to the compiler based on the version info.

I have this version info.

```
#define LUA_VERSION_NUM     503
```

And I want to include the following function only when the version is equal to, or smaller than `501`

```
static void lua_len(lua_State *L, int i) 
{
    //do something
}
```

How is this possible in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM <= 501
static void lua_len(lua_State *L, int i) 
{
    //do something
}
#endif
```

You might want to provide an empty `lua_len` for versions above 501 to prevent compilation errors:

```
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM <= 501
static void lua_len(lua_State *L, int i) 
{
    //do something
}
#else
static void lua_len(lua_State *L, int i) {}
#endif
```

Comment: For versions above Lua 5.1 the function `lua_len` is available, but you couldn't have known since the questions is not tagged [[tag:lua]].

Comment: @HenriMenke What do you mean? Do you think I don't need to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349885/how-to-check-lua-version-in-swig-interface-file

Comment: @ZackLee You don't need the `#else` branch, because Lua 5.2 and up provide `lua_len`.

Comment: Oh, I know that. Thanks for your confirmation.