# How to check Lua version in SWIG interface file?

Tags: c++, lua, c-preprocessor, swig

I have the below function which I would like to use only when the Lua version is equal to, or smaller than `5.1`.

So I wrote it like the following in `myBindings.i` file:

```
/* used to backport lua_len to Lua 5.1 */
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM <= 501
%{
static void lua_len(lua_State *L, int i) 
{
    switch (lua_type(L, i)) 
    {
        case LUA_TSTRING:
            lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number)lua_objlen(L, i));
            break;
        case LUA_TTABLE:
            if (!luaL_callmeta(L, i, "__len"))
            lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number)lua_objlen(L, i));
            break;
        case LUA_TUSERDATA:
            if (luaL_callmeta(L, i, "__len"))
            break;
        default:
        luaL_error(L, "attempt to get length of a %s value",
                   lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, i)));
  }
}
%}
#endif
```

However when I compile the code, the compiler doesn't skip the `lua_len` function in Lua `5.3`.

how can I expose `lua_len` function to the compiler depending on the version info?

Comment: Move the preprocessor macros inside `%{ ... %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You have to move the preprocessor macros inside the literal block `%{ ... %}`.

---

In this scenario

```
#if CONDITION
%{
...
%}
#endif
```

the `CONDITION` is evaluated by SWIG.  SWIG does not know about the macro `LUA_VERSION_NUM` because it is a priori interface agnostic (i.e. you could also generate a Python interface where `LUA_VERSION_NUM` has no meaning).

In the variant

```
%{
#if CONDITION
...
#endif
%}
```

SWIG will forward everything inside the literal block to the interface file.  This will happen literally without any further inspection by SWIG, so preprocessor macros will be untouched.  The C++ compiler will include `<lua.hpp>` and finds a definition of `LUA_VERSION_NUM` there, so the macro will have its intended effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation.